# AutoMapper 3.0 how to map a specific property

Tags: automapper

So the question is how to I send the value
source.SendSomeWhere = "was it sent?"; from origin to the ChildDestination

Below is my attempt... everything works except the source.SendSomeWhere property.

```
  using System;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using AutoMapper;
    namespace UnitTestProject2
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<Origin, Destination>();
                Mapper.CreateMap<OrginChild, ChildDestination>();
                Mapper.CreateMap<Deeper, DeeperDestination>();
                Mapper.CreateMap<Origin, ChildDestination>().ForMember(x=>x.sendSomeWhere,opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.SendSomeWhere)).ForAllMembers(x=>x.Ignore());
                Origin source = new Origin();
                source.Name = "Test";
                source.SendSomeWhere = "was it sent?";
                source.originChild = new OrginChild { Code = "test", Deep = new Deeper { MyCode = "really cool" } };
                Destination dto = Mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
                var sentinel = true;

            }

            public class Origin
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string SendSomeWhere { get; set; }
                public OrginChild originChild { get; set; }
            }
            public class OrginChild
            {
                public string Code { get; set; }
                public Deeper Deep { get; set; }
            }
            public class Deeper
            {
                public string MyCode { get; set; }
            }


            public class Destination
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public ChildDestination originChild { get; set; }
            }

            public class ChildDestination
            {
                public string Code { get; set; }
                public string sendSomeWhere { get; set; }
                public DeeperDestination Deep { get; set; }
            }
            public class DeeperDestination
            {
                public string MyCode { get; set; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Origin, Destination>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.originChild.sendSomeWhere = src.SendSomeWhere);

Mapper.CreateMap<OrginChild, ChildDestination>();

Mapper.CreateMap<Deeper, DeeperDestination>();
```

Comment: Been using AutoMapper for a while now. Also answering questions on SO is a great way to learn.

Comment: The reason why your original map didn't work is because the SendSomeWhere properties are on different levels of your hierarchy. Even more complicated is the destination's property is in a lower level than the source property. AfterMap is one option to grab a parent property's value, a custom resolver would be the other.